# Override method of nested class from method-created class instance

Tags: python, docker, overriding, python-3.7, super

I'm using the Python Docker SDK to send commands to my local docker installation.

```
client = docker.from_env()
client.images.pull(repository=MY_IMAGE, tag="master")
```

What I would like to do is override the `.pull` method so I can add an option so it doesn't pull in some cases.

The easy way would be to add an if-statement before each `.pull`

```
enable_pull=True

if enable_pull:
    client.images.pull(...)
else:
    pass
```

... but I would like to leave the code as-is and just override the method somehow. I'd know how to do it for a "normal" configuration - for example overriding `from_env()` would be easy:

```
class MyClass(docker):
    def from_env(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # my code
        return super().from_env()
```

But how I don't know how I would override `.pull` since it is a method of `.images`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bit of a [`train-wreck`](https://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck) here:  (amplified to make a point)

```py
docker.from_env().images.pull(repository=MY_IMAGE, tag="master")
```

So something like this should be hidden inside one of your own methods:

```py
def pull(self, *args, **kwargs):
    docker.from_env().images.pull(*args, **kwargs)
```

and called like this:

```py
self.pull(repository=MY_IMAGE, tag="master")
```

but you wanted an enable/disable, so:

```py
def pull(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.enable_pull:
        docker.from_env().images.pull(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: this is definitely a way to do it, but I'd have to change any line that has the `.pull` method to use my own method, still. In a perfect world I'd only change the `client`, so `client.images.pull` does what I need it to (react to a flag) without interfering with other functions of `client` (or `client.images` for that matter)

Comment: But this is what the [Law Of Demeter](https://wiki.c2.com/?LawOfDemeter) says about your software. Don't have these repeated train wrecks. When you encapsulate them all, you can change their implementation in one place.